# Siebel crm , how to open url on another machine?

Tags: oracle, siebel

I login to Siebel Retail - ENU crm server using exe and then it opens up URL http://host:8080/start.swe in internet explorer . 
but when i try to open same url (http://host:8080/start.swe) on different machine using ip of siebel server then i get error as :
"This site can’t be reacheds server IP address could not be found.
Search Google for sbl 15ps9 8080 start
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"
or taking to log to respond . 
please find below image for error 
[error screenshot of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tq1o.png)

also when i copy paste same url in new tab then session gets lots .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your quetion according to the [SO model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). For now is not clear what exactly is the error, did you search Google for this error, or this is part of the error itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "Siebel Dedicated Client" and you can use it only locally with one session.

Comment: so is there any way i can use it on different machine ? also can we use extension server SWSE) for dedicated client? is there any way to access the URL from different machine ?